# Get JSONP with Ajax on .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I try to keep data from à json file with cross domain. So i use jsonp but the file have the extension .js, so when i try $.ajax with dataType : 'jsonp' i have an error in console:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
The file is interpret as a javascript file an the request fail. Have you an idea for get data whithout this error.

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://domaine.com/file.js',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    success : function(data){
        console.log(data);
        // no enter in this callback
    },
    complete: function(data1, data2, data3){
        // no data from file.js
    }
});
```

I found file.js when i inspect page in scripts who are load an i can see all information, but with an error because it is considerate as javascript file.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your json to proper jsonp

```
jsonpcallback({"this":"is","my":"json"})
```

Then request it with the given callback:

```
<script>
    function jsonpcallback(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
</script>
<script src="http://domain.com/file.js"></script>
```

You could of course do it with jQuery too:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://domain.com/file.js",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "jsonpcallback",
    success: handler,
    complete: handler,
    error: handler
});
```

Comment: I can't access to file.js, i'can't put this call function 'jsonpcallback'

Comment: If the file.js contains a simple object `{"foo":"bar"}` you can't do anything with it because it will throw a syntax error without the function wrapper. Your only option at that point would be to request it using server-side code or some other proxy such as YQL

Comment: Yeah, i was think that's the only solution, but i was not sure.. I try with YQl. Thanks